# ¿Por qué, en contexto religioso, se sustituye le preposición "con" por "en"?

Tags: preposiciones

Encuentro muchas frases como "regocijaos en el Señor" o "unidos en el Señor" pero los mismos verbos se usarían con la preposición "con" en otros contextos. Algunos ejemplos: "regocijaos con tus hijos" o "unidos con los mexicanos".

Soy consciente que otras preposiciones se podrían usar, por ejemplo, "unidos por los mexicanos", aún así, me parece que la preposición "en" no tiene sentido con ninguno de los ejemplos que mencioné.

Comment: Una de las definiciones en el DLE de _en_ es: **8.** prep. desus. **con**. Aunque no sé si en entornos religiosos se usara *en el Señor* para enfatizar que Dios es todo y todo está en él.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por suerte o por desgracia he tenido que traducir algunos textos religiosos (normalmente medievales) escritos en latín, y la preposición que se usa en este tipo de fórmulas es *in*, con lo que tiene que ser un puro arcaísmo por influencia del latín.

Comment: El tema va más allá, y hay un trasfondo teológico: en un momento importante de la Misa se dice "por Cristo, con Él y en Él", y proviene de una distinción de significado entre las preposiciones. El "en" añade un matiz al "por" y al "con". Voy a buscar a ver si encuentro una fuente